# Angular constant undefined in the configuration phase of another module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code that describes my main i18n module:

```
angular
  .module('myApp.i18n', ['pascalprecht.translate', 'myApp.i18n.constants'])
  .config(config);

config.$inject = ['$translateProvider', 'crTranslations'];
function config($translateProvider, crTranslations) {
    $translateProvider.translations('sr-latn', crTranslations.sr);
    $translateProvider.translations('en', crTranslations.en);
    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('sr-latn');
};
```

And I have another module which contains the following code:

```
angular
    .module('myApp.i18n.constants', [])
    .constant("crTranslations", crTranslations);

var crTranslations = {
    "en": {
        //english translations
    },
    "sr": {
        //serbian translations
    }
}
```

I've included both script files in my index.html and both modules get loaded (the constants before the main one), but the crTranslations constant is undefined in the configuration function.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't related to how Angular modules are managed. `var crTranslations` is declared before `.constant("crTranslations", crTranslations)` statement, due to [JS hoisting](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp), but is assigned to object only after that.